# When should start the writing

Tags: toddler, pre-schooler, handwriting

I am Burmese.  I have a 3 year old baby.  There is a dispute among the mothers of our country as to when writing should begin.  When is it appropriate to expect that a child learn to write?

Comment: Hi Julie, welcome to Parenting.  I've attempted to focus your question - is this what you're aiming to find out, when it's correct to *Expect* a children to learn to write?  Or is it something else, such as when it it appropriate to being *teaching* a child to write?  Please clarify if needed with the "edit" link.  Thanks!

Comment: Also - please see other questions under the [tag:handwriting] tag, such as this one: https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/37574/should-you-teach-your-children-to-identify-letters-or-write-letters-first